# I would like to create one form with multiple records or entries created.

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I create a single form, but have certain fields post to a new row or record? right now all data gets posted to a single record/row. I need to have 5 records created from one form.

Comment: Are you posting into a database?

Comment: Ultimately, I want to be able to pull from Cognito forms via a python script that also pulls from other locations. Then output a CSV or similar. I am trying to keep my users from having to fill out 5 separate forms, but save as separate entries. It would nice if they could fill out one form, but I could get the data to post to separate records.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the form you are building?  Perhaps a screenshot to provide context to your question?